# Regex between last two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a querstion about simple regex. I need to get between of these characters: `-` and `~`

My string: `Champions tour - To Win1 - To Win2 ~JIM FURYK`

When I use this: `\-([^)]+\~)` it is giving as matched this:

```
To Win1 - To Win2 ~
```

But I need this:

```
To Win2 ~JIM FURYK
```

Is it possible to this?

My regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/fJBLXb/1/

Comment: But `To Win2 ~JIM FURYK` is not between `-` and `~`.

Comment: Look at positive look ahead/look behind. They should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `\-([^)]+\~)` regex matches the *leftmost* `-` that is directly followed with one or more chars other than `)` (so  it matches `-`, `a`, `§`, etc.) and then a `~` char. It does not stop at `-` chars and thus can match any amount of hyphens.

To match the value after last hyphen you can use

```js
[^\s-][^-]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1VLuWf/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5B%5E%5Cs-%5D%5B%5E-%5D*%24). *Details*:

- `[^\s-]` - a char other than whitespace and `-`
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'Champions tour - To Win1 - To Win2 ~JIM FURYK';
const match = text.match(/[^\s-][^-]*$/);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\-([^-)]+\~)` - dash to not match

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` as follows:

```js
var input = "Champions tour - To Win1 - To Win2 ~JIM FURYK";
var output = input.match(/- ([^-]+~.*)$/)[1];
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern used above says to match:

```regex
-          a hyphen
[ ]        a single space
(          capture what follows
    [^-]+  match all content WITHOUT crossing another hyphen
    ~      ~
    .*     all remaining content
)          stop capture
$          end of the string
```